# ¿Como pasar datos de una tabla en sql server a una tabla en Mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Buen día, tengo un problema.
Tengo una tabla en sql server con datos que ocupo trabajar. 
Esos datos de sql server, los quiero mandar a una tabla que esta en Mysql, ya que en Mysql es el gestor en el que voy a trabajar, pero necesito esos datos de sql server para poder hacer operación con las cantidades. 
Intente pasarlos, primero llenando un datagridview en C# y de ahí hacer un insert a la tabla de Mysql, pero no me funciono.
Tendrán algún consejo que me puedan dar o guiarme por algún camino en el cual pueda hacer el cambio. 
Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias. 
Que tengan buen día.

Comment: Hola, para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta y así aumentar las posibilidades de poder ayudarte, te recomiendo que revises la página de ayuda sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Podrías comenzar por compartir un poco del código que vas escribiendo. Saludos!!

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, es imposible decirte cual es tu problema si no nos muestras el código de como estás intentando agregar la información a la base de datos MySQL

Comment: cuando dices que no funciona lo que intentaste, es por algun mensaje de error? podrias poner ese codigo que "intentaste" y vemos de arreglarlo

Comment: el pasaje de datos desde sql server a mysql tiene que ser usando codigo?, o sea es algo que se hara repetidas veces o podria hacerse directo entre las base de datos

Comment: Se hará repetidas veces y esa información que tendré almacenada en mysql alimentará un reporte, pero definitivamente la información de sql server se tendrá que pasar repetidas veces a mysql, así que si se puede hacer directo estaría bien o el método que me puedan recomendár se los agradecería.

Comment: pero es una actualizacion constante de los datos o cada tanto ? lo pregunt porque se podria realizar mediante un link server en sql server y volvar los datos con una query. Si es algo que debe actualizarse con la interaccion del usuario en la app entonces edita la pregunta y pon el codigo que has implementado hasta el momento